NavigationStack return to root crash in preview, works in Simulator
I am running into a crash issue with what seems like a super simple project. This all works in Preview up until the home button is pressed in the Info view. It flashes back to the Colors list, then crashes. Interestingly, it works in the Similar with no issues. This is on an M2 Pro MacBook Pro running Ventura/Xcode 13.3.1. I haven't upgraded yet because I have read enough horror stories about Sonoma, especially with respect to Parallels Desktop, which I need to keep running for a little longer.
My question is, is this a problem in my code that I am missing, or a bug that I just need to work around and accept for now? And, is there anything in the crash dump that might be helpful? I have looked through it and I can't find anything that defines WHY I got a crash, but it might as well be in Klingon as far as my comprehension of what I am reading. :)
AppEntry.swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct AppEntry: App {
    @StateObject var router = Router()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack(path: $router.path) {
                ContentView()
            }
            .environmentObject(router)
        }
    }
}

class Router: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path:NavigationPath = NavigationPath()
    
    func back() {
        path.removeLast()
    }
    func reset() {
        path = NavigationPath()
    }
}

ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var router: Router
    private var colors: [Color] = [.indigo, .yellow, .green, .orange, .brown]
    var body: some View {
            List(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                NavigationLink(color.description, value: color)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationTitle("Colors")
            .navigationDestination(for: Color.self) { color in
                ColorView(color: color)
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(Router())
        }
    }
}

ColorView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct ColorView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var router: Router
    var color: Color
    var body: some View {
        color
        .navigationTitle(color.description.capitalized)
        .toolbar {
            NavigationLink("info", value: true)
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Bool.self) { bool in
            TextView()
        }
    }
}

struct ColorView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ColorView(color: .green)
                .environmentObject(Router())
        }
    }
}

TextView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct TextView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var router: Router
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
                .frame(alignment: .leading)
                .padding()
        }
        Spacer()
        .navigationTitle("info")
        .toolbar {
            Button ("home") {
                router.reset()
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct TextView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TextView()
                .environmentObject(Router())
        }
    }
}


Put the injection code on the NavigationStack not in it

@lorem-ipsum I thought being below the closing } of the NavigationStack meant it was ON not IN. Double checked, and also tried moving it to ON in all the Previews, hoping that was where I was wrong. Now the Home button does nothing in Preview, but it all still works in the Simulator. Spooky. :) Interesting that it works both ways on the simulator.

And double checked, moved everything to IN, and now I am back to crashing.

Is Preview crashing or simulator/device. In the code you posted all the injection lines are IN not ON, they should be ON. Also none of your previews are actually using the path.

@lorem-ipsum Only previews, I start from ContentView & navigate to TextView then try to use the home button and get the crash. As for injection location, as I look at the original code, all the Previews are IN, but the AppEntry injection is ON. Is that your understanding as well? And how would one make the preview use the path? The approach of giving the preview a new .environmentObject(Router()) and the NavigationStack being initialised without a path is consistent with a number of different examples, from Stewart Lynch and others. But all of those are also more than a year old.

You need something similar to your App file. That pattern is consistent with examples but the difference with your code and the examples is that you need a StateObject in the preview so you can bind with the stack

OK, will play around. Weirdly I have another in process project, a ToDo list, that uses something similar to complete the AddItem process, and that IS working with previews done as here, but for the life of my I can't find what ELSE is different. Grr.

And interestingly, if I print to console in a version I am playing with now, with a homeButtonPressed function, as well as print to console in the reset function of the  Router, and both report as if they are working. It's just actually changing the path that seems to not happen.
